# Getting rid of the double click on iPad

Tags: jquery, mobile-safari

I have this all set up the way i want it only to find that when i'm using an ipad i have to touch the link twice to activate it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.normal-model').live('mouseover', function () {
        jQuery(this).find('.desc-box').fadeIn('slow');
        var videoid = jQuery(this).find('.model-video a').attr('id');
        var viddestin = jQuery(this).find('.model-video');
        var postoi = jQuery(this).find('.model-video iframe');
        if (postoi.length == 0) {
            if (videoid != '' || videoid != ' ') {
                var genifr = '<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoid + '?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" width="230" height="150"></iframe>';
            }
            jQuery(genifr).appendTo(viddestin);
        }
    });
    jQuery('.normal-model').live('mouseleave', function () {
        jQuery(this).find('.desc-box').fadeOut('slow');
        jQuery(this).find('.model-video iframe').remove();
    });
});
```

How to get it to only be clicked once on iPad?

Comment: It's hard to follow this code when you put it all on a single line.  This question has a much higher chance of getting a good answer if the code is spread across several lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPads don't have a `mouseover` or `mouseleave` event. Try using `touchstart` and `touchend` (or just `touch`) in addition to your `mouse` events (and also know that `.live` is deprecated in favor of [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on)):

```
jQuery('.normal-model').on('mouseover touch', function () {

// ...

jQuery('.normal-model').on('mouseleave touch', function () {
```

Comment: Awsome! thanks for the edit and also for solving my problem! Changed .live to .on and also added  a 'touchstart' and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You are binding a mouseover event to the element. Since touch devices don't have regular hover events, they solve this by making sure a tap on an element gets treated as a hover event when you tap it. The second tap (doubleclick) activates the normal click event.

Tldr; don't use hover events for this kind of navigation if you want to offer a good experience on your iPad. Just change the binding to a click event.